# force IIS to use x-Forwarded-For/CF-Connecting-IP for IP Restrictions

Tags: iis-10

How to force IIS to use **x-Forwarded-For**/**CF-Connecting-IP** instead of **c-ip** for IP Restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [IIS URL Rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to accomplish this, add a new inbound rule with conditions that check to see if the IP address does not match {HTTP_X_Forwarded_For}, you can then set the rule up to redirect, rewrite, or abort the request.

Comment: yes, just tested. it works. thanks. I'm figuring out can it be more advance by only block other ips except certain ip for sub path of request url respectively

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "[Accept Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)" and upvote it.

Comment: What is more advance?  here a link about [preventing automated attacks with IIS dynamic IP restrictions](https://blogs.iis.net/peterviola/preventing-automated-attacks-with-iis-dynamic-ip-restrictions) that meets your requirement? you can set IP address block in IP Address and Domain Restrictions.